# How to apply a style to the modify interaction in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a GeoJSON vector layer with polygons. When the user clicks on a polygon, it should be highlighted a certain way. That works fine this way:

```
selectStyle = new ol.style.Style({ ... });
map = new ol.Map({ ... });
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  style: selectStyle
});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

Now there's an option to edit the selected polygon. I do it like this:

```
modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: select.getFeatures(),
  // style: modifyStyle // does not work!
});  
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

Now I want to apply once more another style to the polygon that is edited, however, I couldn't figure out how. Applying the style option to the modify interaction as shown above (commented out) doesn't seem to work. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the style option in `ol.interaction.Select` caused my problem. If a style is set to a feature explicitly with `feature.setStyle()`, the style option in `ol.interaction.Select` won't apply anymore. I got it to work by assigning the styles explicitly.

First I set the default style to the layer:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: defaultStyle
});
```

Now I set the select styles with listeners:

```
var collection = select.getFeatures();
collection.on('add', addSelectionListener);
collection.on('remove', removeSelectionListener); 

function addSelectionListener(){
  var collection = select.getFeatures();
  collection.forEach(function(feature){
  feature.setStyle(selectStyle);
  });
}

function removeSelectionListener(){
  var collection = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
  collection.forEach(function(feature){
  feature.setStyle(defaultStyle);
  });
}
```

When modifying a feature, I assign the modify style:

```
modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: select.getFeatures()
});  
map.addInteraction(modify);

var collection = select.getFeatures();
collection.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setStyle(modifyStyle);
});
```

Finally, after finishing the feature modification I reassign the default style:

```
map.removeInteraction(modify);

var collection = select.getFeatures();
collection.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setStyle(defaultStyle);
});

select.getFeatures().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`modifyend`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.ModifyEvent.html#event:modifyend) event and loop through modified features:

```
modify.on('modifyend', function(evt){
    var collection = evt.features;

    collection.forEach(function(feature){
        feature.setStyle(style_modify);
    });
});
```

Comment: What I actually need are different styles to indicate "select mode" and "edit mode". So applying "modifyStyle" directly without `modify.on(...)` already does what I need. However, after editing, I need to reapply the default style, which seems to prevent applying the select style in `ol.interaction.Select` when I select a feature again after editing it.

Comment: Well, use my answer to apply any style (default, or other) after editing.